# Device pixel ratio undefined

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am using javascript to see a cookie to the device pixel ratio. In IE device pixel ratio outputs undefined, so I want to use a conditional to say, if undefined set as 1.

I have been trying a few different approaches, but thought this would work:

```
<script>
                    if (window.devicePixelRatio==undefined) {
                        document.cookie='screenpixelratio='1'; path=/';location.reload(true);
                    } else {
                        document.cookie='screenpixelratio='+window.devicePixelRatio+'; path=/';location.reload(true);
                    }
                </script>
```

But, I cant get it to output 1.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure that the '1' should go within quotes?

Comment: @PaulJ: That's an answer. It could even be *the* answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PaulJ points out in the comments on the question that you have a syntax error in your code:

```
document.cookie='screenpixelratio='1'; path=/';location.reload(true);
// Here --------------------------^
```

The `'` terminates the string, and so the `1` is an invalid token at that point. You probably meant:

```
document.cookie='screenpixelratio=1; path=/';location.reload(true);
```

If that's not it, my original answer was:

I'd've thought that would work, but this may work better:

```
if (typeof window.devicePixelRatio === "undefined") {
```

Technically, it's possible for something to be `undefined` but not the same `undefined` as the one you're using to compare it to, but this is typically only in cross-window situations.

Or this may get more directly to the point (finding out whether there's a `devicePixelRatio` property on `window`):

```
if (!('devicePixelRatio' in window)) {
```

Comment: @ Prisoner: "I'd've" is a perfectly valid contraction.

Comment: Never seen I'd've written before, so I had to check it up. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/689/is-idve-proper-use-of-the-english-language - seems ok in fictional but not in formal writing. What do I really care though :)

Comment: @Prisoner: You have to take into account who hangs out at english.stackexchange.com and answers questions... ;-)